# gdb: logging something instead of breaking?

Tags: unix, logging, gdb

Is it possible to have gdb log something to the terminal instead of breaking on it?  For example I would like to set a 'breakpoint' on some method and have gdb print self as well as the parameters each time the method is invoked. Basically I want to insert print statements into arbitrary places without actually recompiling.

thanks for any suggestions

---

This is what i have so far after these helpful comments:

```
define logFoo
b fooMethod
commands
po self
end
end
```

GDB doesn't seem to like the nested end statements though. any thoughts?

Comment: For future reference, the double end thing is a known bug. The solution is to put the inner block in a separate text file and use source to load it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Breakpoint Command Lists](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands). There is an example how to do it.

> For example, here is how you could use
>   breakpoint commands to print the value
>   of x at entry to foo whenever x is
>   positive.
>
> ```
>  break foo if x>0
>  commands
>  silent
>  printf "x is %d\n",x
>  cont
>  end
> ```

Comment: awesome.  One thing though. The symbol (method) i want to break on is a pretty common thing, so it may need to set up many breakpoints.  How do I attach commands to each one without having to manually do 100 tiimes?

Answer (score 3):

Use a breakpoint as usual, and set a macro to log and continue:

```
 define c
 print "foo"
 cont
 c
 end
```

Comment: nice. can you elaborate a bit?  So I can define this macro in my gdbinit file, but how do I tell gdb to call this macro when a breakpoint occurs?

Comment: Why both `cont` and `c` here, aren't those the same?

Comment: @warl0ck: this is redefining `c` to be a "recursively continue while logging stuff" command.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can only hook into the symbols of the code and machine code. If you want to log output you will need a logging functionality.

If you are tracing specific errors try conditional breakpoints and watch variables.

EDIT:

Even while not directly loggin it could be an alternative to use GDB [command files](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#Command-Files)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm finding it hard to believe that this is not possible though.  I could easily do something like break hitTest:withEvent: , then when it breaks to po self, p point to see the info I want.  How can this not be automated to have gdb just print this without having me actually tell it to do so each time it breaks?

Comment: As crazy as this might sound, there might be a chance to use some kind of macros to perform what you want, but it is still not directly logging. Checkout this: http://tromey.com/blog/?p=548