# Android NDK - Debugging a random crash with a bad callstack

Tags: android, android-ndk

My android native application crashes randomly but frequently, and I am unable to get sufficient info out ndk-gdb. This is the message following the crash:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 19983]
0x4012c6ac in memcpy () from /Users/Andreas/dev/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
```

bt returns an unusable callstack:

```
#0  0x4012c6ac in memcpy () from /Users/Andreas/dev/android/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
#1  0x67337388 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x7
#2  0x67337388 in ?? ()
Cannot access memory at address 0x7
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I am using NDK-r8e

I have checked all uses of `memcpy()` in my program and they're not responsible for this (verified by making them call another memcpy-like function with a different name, and still getting the above crash with the exact signature).

Any ideas how to get a more useable call stack, or to further debug this? Does the NDK offer any memory check functionality in case this is a memory overwrite?

Comment: Perhaps you can run under gdb, put a breakpoint on memcpy and use a macro to have it print a back trace and then continue, until you get the crash (which presumably corrupts the stack).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206447/gdb-logging-something-instead-of-breaking for the breakpoint log and continue macros.  Log the arguments too, as they are likely the culprit!

Comment: To get a more usable stacktrace, you can try building your NDK code in debug mode so it does not strip the symbols. Use `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1` to do so.

Comment: @mbrenon - I believe that would only help with *interpreting* the stack trace, ie, address to symbol resolution.  The problem right now is that even a trace of raw addresses cannot be generated.  Doing so is trickier on an ARM given the way return addresses are stored, and can easily become corrupted such that the debugger can't figure it out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - thanks for the suggestion. I am however getting bad callstacks for the breaks to memcpy, similar to the one I posted above. Other breakpoints to my code work correctly, and I am building in debug and have no problems with callstacks elsewhere.

Comment: Wait, every call to memcpy, even the non-failing ones, has a bad call stack?  Or I suppose that in addition to memcpy being called with bad values, it could be being called as a result of state corruption.

Comment: I'm new to android, but I'd be inclined to think the bad call stack is an issue with the tools. The program can't be corrupting memory that often, it's a codebase that uses memcpy very often and is very stable on many other platforms. I'm not even sure memcpy is related to this.

Comment: Simple test would be to add a safe use of memcpy to the hello-jni example, and breakpoint it.  Does the call stack display?  And if in the test you intentionally make the target address 0, do you get a valid stack trace in logcat or a corrupted one?

Comment: Yes, a deliberate bad call to memcpy gives proper callstack, both in my app and in an empty test app.

Comment: There's a `libc.debug.malloc` property that can be set on rooted devices; may or may not be useful (I'm guessing not, given your symptoms).  It's possible, though a bit tricky, to get valgrind running on recent versions of Android.  If gdb is not attached do you get a full stack trace from debuggerd in logcat?  debuggerd uses a different stack unwinder than gdb does, so sometimes one will work when the other doesn't.